# Conversion by presumption

Tags: halacha, conversion-to-judaism, acharonim

[This document](https://issuu.com/tzohar/docs/giyur_final), in the section running over page 11 onto page 12, refers to Rav Feinstein's [chiddush](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49981&st=&pgnum=480&hilite=) that it is possible to 'convert' to Judaism by chazakah alone, and without a formal beit din. The article adds that similar rulings were made by Zachar Yosef, Maharam Shick and Tzafnat Panei'ach.

I'm aware of Tzafnat Panei'ach saying this ([here](https://www.sefaria.org/Tzafnat_Pa%27neach_on_Mishneh_Torah%2C_Forbidden_Intercourse.13.9.1?lang=bi)) but can anyone help with identifying the other two sources?

Many thanks!